# TCP Window size field, does it refer to sender or receiver of segment?

Tags: tcp

As I understand since TCP is connection-oriented there really isn't a single sender and receiver, there is two pipes, each node acts as both sender and receiver. This bring some confusion when Window size is referred to as the available buffer at the receiving side.

So finally, when I observe a TCP segment, is the Window size referring to the buffer at the node receiving it or sending it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receive window is sent by the sender of the segment, in the segment, to indicate to the peer the current space in the sender's receive buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows size is the way to inform the peer about how many data he is ready to receive. In the most problematic case, window equal to cero means the node can not receive more data, the peer must stop sending it until window change.

So, when a node sends a messsage, the windows size refers to its own (sender) window size.